# JSoup fetching table from html page and converting it to JSON

Tags: java, android, json, jsoup

i have a table in a website which i am trying to scrape the table looks like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Region</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>region one</td>
    <td>city one</td>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>active</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>region one</td>
    <td>city two</td>
    <td>102</td>
    <td>active</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>region three</td>
    <td>city three</td>
    <td>103</td>
    <td>inactive</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>region four</td>
    <td>city four</td>
    <td>104</td>
    <td>active</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>region five</td>
    <td>city five</td>
    <td>102</td>
    <td>active</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

i am able to scrape the website using andorid jsoup

```
  Document document = Jsoup.connect("URL").get();
words = document.text();
```

this is where i have gone so far i am unable to isolate the table and put it in JSON

Comment: Have you visited https://jsoup.org/cookbook/? Especially https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this and it works fine

```
 JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
                for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
                    for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
                        Elements tds = row.select("td");
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                        if (tds.size() >= 2)
                        {
                            jsonObject.put("region", tds.get(0).text());
                            jsonObject.put("city", tds.get(1).text());
                            jsonObject.put("code", tds.get(2).text());
                            jsonObject.put("status", tds.get(3).text());
                            list.put(jsonObject);
                        }
                    }
                }
```